# Bitbucket issues section useless when connected to JIRA?

Tags: bitbucket, jira

I have connected Bitbucket repo with JIRA project. Now when I commit to Bitbucket, I can reference JIRA issues or I can create branches in Bitbucket repo from JIRA and view commits from JIRA.

However, when I create an issue in JIRA or an issue in Bitbucket, they are not being synced. I have not found any tutorial about this.

Does this mean that Issues section in Bitbucket is useless when we connect it to JIRA? Is Issues section on Bitbucket only for repos that are not connected to JIRA (and I should turn it off in repos that have JIRA connection?

I am sure this is easy answer for someone who's done these things before.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In short: yes.

A bit longer: 
Bitbucket is a product that was developed separately from JIRA in a different company. Atlassian [bought](http://blogs.atlassian.com/2010/09/weve_gone_into_the_code_hosting_business/) [Bitbucket](https://techcrunch.com/2010/09/29/atlassian-buys-mercurial-project-hosting-site-bitbucket/) a couple years ago. Bitbucket already contained a simple issue tracker and it still does, but its focus is hosting source code. JIRA's focus is managing issues, and Atlassian has provided excellent [integration between JIRA and Bitbucket](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/use-bitbucket-cloud-with-jira-applications-813891605.html). So, if you use both then there really is no need to still use Bitbucket's issue tracker.

The full details of the integration are described on the page I linked before, but some examples are:

- JIRA issues display a "development tools panel" that shows the commits made for the issue + a link to easily create a branch for the issue.
  [image]
- The JIRA releases view shows information about commits
  [image]
- In Bitbucket issue keys are rendered as links so you can easily navigate to JIRA.
- ...

Comment: Thanks. So it means that a programmer has to use both Bitbucket and JIRA? For example, I will go to JIRA to see issue ID and create a branch in Bitbucket, and then commit changes to the corresponding branch and reference issue via its ID. This is the flow?

Comment: Yes. But, if you have set up the link between JIRA and Bitbucket and you added "Bitbucket" in the "development tools" section of your JIRA project, then when you view an issue, the "development tools" panel will also display a link to create branches, so you don't necessarily have to navigate to Bitbucket yourself. To make it clear to bitbucket which info is related to JIRA issues, you have to include the issue key in both your branch names and commit messages.

Comment: I've added a few examples and screenshots about what the integration offers. There's more than that, but best to check the docs to get all the details. At least this should give an idea.