# How to sync bitbucket issues and JIRA issues

Tags: git, bitbucket, jira

I find how to sync issues in real time. 
I imported Bitbucket issues and used DVCS accounts.
So. now I watch bitbucket's commit, pull request, branches and Issues that already exist.
I hope to know when someone write an issues in Bitbucket, using JIRA.
please help me..

(how to connect issues bitbucket clound and JIRA Server)

Comment: Chris's answer is fine. There's also a related question and answer here: [Bitbucket issues section useless when connected to JIRA?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38460873/bitbucket-issues-section-useless-when-connected-to-jira/38462474#38462474)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Connecting Bitbucket Cloud and JIRA Server is a [two step process](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/connect-bitbucket-cloud-to-jira-server-applications-814208991.html):

- In Bitbucket Cloud, create an OAuth token with the following permissions:

  - **Account: Write**
  - **Repositories: Admin**, but *not* Repositories: Write
  - **Pull requests: Read**
- As an admin user, add your Bitbucket OAuth token to JIRA Server's **DVCS Accounts** integration

However, note that when Bitbucket and JIRA are linked JIRA completely replaces Bitbucket Issues. You don't end up with two sets of synced issues, you end up with Bitbucket version control and JIRA issues.